How record video with AVFoundation and save in external drive?
I'm trying to create a camera app and would like to add video recording to an external drive. My application is still able to record videos to temporary storage, and only then saves the video to the photos system application.
The task is this, you need to record directly to an external drive, I transfer the link to the external drive via UserDefaults, adding the file name and file format.
Is it even possible to pull this off, this is how Black magic camera can do it.
I will provide the code below.
I signed my controller to the UIDocumentPickerDelegate subclass, thanks to it I get a link to an external drive
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        if let urlData = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: urls.first ?? "", requiringSecureCoding: false) {
            defaults.set(urlData, forKey: "URL")
        } else {
            print("Failed to archive URL")
        }
    }

When you click the record button, it has this code
 if let urlData = defaults.data(forKey: "URL"),
               let url = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(urlData) as? URL {
                
                let stringURL = url.path
                let stringCombine = stringURL + "/" + UUID().uuidString + ".mov"
                fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: stringCombine)
                cameraService.recordMode(self.fileURL!)
            }

as soon as recording begins, the error condition is immediately worked out and output to the console:
Cannot create file
extension CaptureSession: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    
    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput,
                    didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL,
                    from connections: [AVCaptureConnection],
                    error: Error?)  {
        if let fileError = error {
            print(fileError.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            do {
                try PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChangesAndWait {
                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputFileURL)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}


Running in Sandbox?
